# Is it possible to create my new Windows 7 install inside VirtualBox VM then migrate it onto my hard drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I need to reinstall windows 7 but I want to see if I can create the new install inside virtualbox and install some programs and throw my drivers in a folder, then boot ghost or something similar to install it on to my existing hard drive. I have an external USB hard drive I can use to do this part. I just don't know very much about virtualbox or ghost but I've messed around a bit with VMs.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Have you made any progress?

Answer (score 0):

Although I have heard many great things about VirtualBox, I have never known someone who has actually done this with that software.  Hopefully someone can chime in who has experience in that regard.

Personally, I have reloaded literally hundreds of Windows 7 physical workstations and there may be a much more simple way to achieve your desired end-state result:

1. Backup the pertinent files and folders `(Desktop, Documents, Downloads, Favorites, Music, Pictures, Videos)` on the current Windows 7 machine.
2. Utilize that external USB drive to save a copy of the `%SystemDrive%\Windows\System32\DriverStore` folder.
3. Ensure that you have the appropriate product key for your software applications.
4. Perform the full wipe-and-reload of the Windows 7 operating system.
5. Check the `Device Manager` for any missing hardware drivers.
6. If there *are* missing hardware drivers, right-click on each one and select `Update Driver Software`.
7. Within the ensuing GUI, point it at the `DriverStore` folder on the external USB drive and use the option to search sub-folders, also.

Once you are done, you should have a clean install of Windows 7 with all of the drivers from the previous build and you can install any programs that you need.

Hopefully that helps out a bit.